# My IIS Default page is always popups up

Tags: iis

I'm trying IIS Website setting on my local computer.(WIN 7 64)

But my `default.aspx` always popups up and I don`t know why. Can somebody give me a clue?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Why?

Comment: I want to open a default.aspx in normal page(not popup).

Comment: with same source in server, it opens with normal page(not popup)

Comment: So you are saying that when you browse something like `http://localhost:8080/default.aspx` in a new browser tab then it pop-ups another dialog window instead of opening it in the current browser tab. Is it?

Comment: Yes!! your right!!